# SSH Tunnel between to 2 computers using a gateway server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I want to create an ssh tunnel between 2 computers. This is my current setup:

```
Fig. 1
---------     SSH     -----------     SSH    ---------
|   A   |  ---------> | Gateway | <--------- |   B   |
---------             -----------            ---------

Fig. 2
----------  :7575       Tunnel        :7575  ----------
| Server | <-------------------------------- | Client |
----------                                   ----------
```

A and B can SSH to the Gateway, but the Gateway cannot SSH to either A or B.

A runs on Linux and B runs on Windows and connects the gateway via PuTTY.

How can I create an tunnel (seen in Fig. 2) so that the client software on B can connect to the Server on A?

Comment: Is there a problem with installing  and configuring a sshd on the server?

Comment: No, I don't how to "connect" those two ssh session to create a tunnel from B to A. A and B are behind a NAT, that's why the gateway server can't connect to A or B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

- At B with putty: ssh to gateway. Right click window top, under connection ssh/tunnels add tunnel: localport 7575, destination 127.0.0.1:7575 - don't forget to click Apply before close.
- At S with OS ssh command: `ssh -R7575:127.0.0.1:7575 gateway`
  This reverse tunnel connects the end of the A-initiated tunnel to your port 7575 on B.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!